# login page redirect to main index page

Tags: django

im new to django.
actually i want on correct login user it redirect to my index page.
here is my login handler.

```
def login(request):
    template = "../templates/admin/login.html"
    data = {
        }
    user = auth.authenticate(username='aa', password='bb')
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        template = "../templates/admin/index.html"

        auth.login(request, user)

    return render_to_response( template, data, 
                               context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )
```

---

here is my html file of login.

```
<form id="FormName11" action="/login/" method="post" class="prettyformlogin" name="FormName11">
{% csrf_token %}

<table width='448' border='0' cellspacing='2' cellpadding='0'>
<tr> <td><b>Username</b></td><td><input id='username' type='text' name='username'> </td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Password</b></td><td><input id='password' type='password' name='password'></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Login'></td></tr>
```

---

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a [HttpResponseRedirect](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect)

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup Django decorators and setup the settings for it to work. Here is a link for Django Decorators https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/

Add these to your settings.py:

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/homepage/'

Just change the values according to your specifications. (/login/ and /homepage/ are URLs).

Answer (score 0):

if you will use a default login handler - there is a [default setting](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`.