# django page redirect on success login

Tags: django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [login page redirect to main index page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472191/login-page-redirect-to-main-index-page)

im not getting exactly.. actually on httpresponse redirect it show nothing.
actually on http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/ in show my login page 
now i want on correct login it will redirect to my index page.
dont the exact way.

```
def login(request):
    template = "../templates/admin/login.html"
    data = {
        }
    user = auth.authenticate(username='aa', password='bb')
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        template = "../templates/admin/index.html"

        auth.login(request, user)
     return HttpResponseRedirect("/login/index/")

return render_to_response( template, data, 
                           context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )
```

thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your question to indent the code by four spaces so that it is readable please.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman seemingly from the same user as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the default login handler, with the [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) setting.